# can someone explaine how setstate work inside useffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i find a code that show loading before fetching data and shows "downloaded " after the fetching is ended the code is working ,however i couldn't understand how this code is working for my understanding
the useEffect() will run one time when the app start and usestate() will rerender the component every time loading value changed so ,in the beginning of the code the useeffect() will run ,and setloading willchange the value to true and rerender the component ,for my point of vue it look like there is infinite loop of rendering can someone please explaine how usestate worke inside of useffect and how this code is working.
this is the code:

````
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function Assemble(){
const [loading,setloading]=useState(true);
useEffect(()=>{
   setloading(true);
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  setloading(false);
},[])
   return(<div>
      <div>{loading?"Loading":"downloaded"}</div>
   </div>)
} ```
````

Comment: "how does it work" might be too broad a question.  The infinite loop is avoided by not rendering if the state doesn't change.  Maybe you should talk more about why you are convinced there is an infinite loop?

Comment: "*it look like there is infinite loop of rendering*" - no. As you said, "*the `useEffect()` will run one time when the app start*" (or more accurately when the component is mounted), because of the `[]` dependency list. It won't run again after that.

Comment: @Wyck i think because inside useffect there is setloading that change loading and rerender the component , when the component rerender it run useeffect  again and setloading ....

Comment: It's true that's an infinite loop, but the `[]` dependency list is empty so nothing will trigger a second iteration of the loop. Consider reading about the _dependency list_ [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)   or maybe [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base#example-2) also explains it not too badly. Basically useEffect will by default always render, unless you tell it explicitly what part of the state to watch for changes (the dependencies), which, if empty, will never re-render.

Comment: @Bergi for my point of vue it look like when when the component is mounted it run setloading that rerender the component immediately without executing the The rest of the code if you can explain the process of how this code work ?

Comment: @Wyck but in that case setloading(false) will never get called

Comment: well, the code itself is broken.  It should probably have `setLoading(false)` as yet another `.then` clause, don't you think?  e.g.: `.then(json => console.log(json)).then(() =>   setloading(false));`

Comment: @polaris877goodman What do you mean by "*without executing the rest of the code*"? The effect callback is run by react after the function component has returned a value.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, the useEffect can get 2 arguments as parameters, 1 of them being the function that should be run, and the second one being an array (in your case it was []) which mentions upon the change of which dependencies should the first function be executed.

Now, because you used [] and left it empty, that means the useEffect will only run once.